# How to refer to a method in the inline code from the code-behind file?

Tags: c#, asp.net

The IsPrime method **should** be in a separate class in the App_Code folder, but I want to understand why this doesn't work and how to make it work.

The build error is in default.cs:
**"The name 'IsPrime' does not exist in the current context"**

[image: The build error]

Here is the code behind, default.cs:

```
using System;
public partial class _Default : System.Web.UI.Page {
    protected void btnGo_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
        lblAnswer.Text = IsPrime(Convert.ToInt32(txtNumber.Text));
    }
}
```

Here is the markup, default.aspx:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="Default.aspx.cs" Inherits="_Default" %>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

<%@ Import Namespace="System" %>
<%@ Page Language="c#"%>

<script runat="server">
    public partial class _Default : System.Web.UI.Page {
        static public Boolean IsPrime(int num) {
            Boolean isPrime = true;
            int limit = num / 2;
            for (int i = 2; i < limit; i++) {
                if (num % i == 0) { isPrime = false; break; }
            }
            return isPrime;
        }
    }
</script>

<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
        <asp:TextBox ID="txtNumber" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
    </div>
    <div>
        <asp:Button runat="server" ID="btnGo" OnClick="btnGo_Click" Text="Go" />
    </div>
    <div>
        <asp:label runat="server" ID="lblAnswer" />
    </div>

    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I'd suggest move that inline code block to the code behind file. It's not very intuitive to have both a code behind file and an inline code block.

Comment: Any specific reason for that `IsPrime` method inside the `<script>` tag?? and whats wrong with including them in the code behind>?

Comment: The IsPrime method *should* be in a separate class in the App_Code folder, but I want to understand why this doesn't work.

Comment: I deleted my answer because actually the static modifier shouldn't matter. The only other thing that occurred to me was the namespace. Have you tried using a custom namespace in both files, i.e. something like `namespace defaultNamespace` and `<%@ Import Namespace="defaultNamespace" %>
`

Answer (score 0):

I changed the reference to IsPrime in Default.cs to

```
default_aspx.IsPrime(...)
```

Evidently the inline code is put in a class called default_aspx

Comment: the code behind is being compiled before loading the inline so it doesn't know about the inline method.

Comment: All the squiggles are gone and the project builds, so it must know about the method at some point.